# how to integrate openCV and ARtoolkit

Tags: opencv, flartoolkit

I need to use both openCV and ARtoolkit libraries in the same project. I'm trying to get frame by using arVideoGetImage() function in order to process for with openCV functions. however program throws a "System.AccessViolationException" error in the following line of face detection example:
CvSeq *faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(img, cascade, storage, 1.1, 3, 0, cvSize( 40, 40 ));

ARtoolkit and openCV are work perfectly separately. Anyone has able to work these two library together, or any suggestion??

thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/mail-archive/message-thread-00488-Intel-OpenCV-for-ARToolK.html

Answer (score 1):

http://se.cs.ait.ac.th/cvwiki/opencv:tutorial:integrate_opencv_and_artoolkit